# How to make a glyphicon clickable and change its appearance without using a button in Play Framework 2.3.8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, playframework

I have a blue glyphicon in the form of an arrow-up.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" style="color:blue"></span>
```

Now if I click on it, I want to change the color of it to red and then count up a number next to it.
I've seen several solutions where a button with a glyphicon on it is used to change the appearance / glyphicon, but I am wondering if it is possible to just use a glyphicon and toggle the color. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to the span-tag, and create an other span for the number.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#' + id_from_span_tag).click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css("color", "red");
        var num = $('#' + id_from_other_span);
        var currentNumber = num.text().length ? parseInt(num.text()) : 0;
        num.text(currentNumber + 1);
    });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/Lnrg7wL4/1/)

Comment: The fiddle works fine and does exactly what I want, BUT I cant get it to work in my playframework app.
I have put the script into the index.scala.html, with and without <script>-tags.
But only the word "Icon" is show, not the number. And if I click on it, nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, I hit return before I was finished. See my edit in my last response please.

Comment: do you have this, `<span id="icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" style="color:blue"> Icon</span><span id="num"></span>` between your body tag? the Id attributes are very important! the javascript code has to be on the same page in `<script type="text/javascript">......</script>`

Comment: It kind of works then...

In my main.scala.html: 
`<body>
     <span id="icon">Icon</span><span id="num"></span>
     @content
</body>`

This is in my index.scala.html:
`<script>
$('#icon').click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.css("color", "red");
var num = $('#num');
var currentNumber = num.text().length ? parseInt(num.text()) : 0;
num.text(currentNumber + 1);
});
</script>`

If I try to put the "Icon" into my index.scala.html too, it wont work. I thought, that index.scala.html gets put into the @content-part, which is inside of the body tags?

[EDIT]: Formating is hard here

Comment: i modified my above answer, so that the script runs when the DOM is built (not earlier). If this still not work, put the above script into main.scala.html (of course in script-tags ;-)) edit: i know :D create a fiddle instead, if there is too much code.

Comment: Thanks it works. Seems like I have to learn jQuery / javascript when I want to use the play framework. I'll have to figure out now how to build a template where I can put several up-arrows into. I appreciate your help and your patience :)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery's .css() you can change the color on your icon when the icon is clicked.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/css/